# How to determine if a string is a substring of another in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to see if a string is inside *a portion* of another string.
e.g.:

```
'ab' in 'abc' -> true
'ab' in 'bcd' -> false
```

How can I do this in a conditional of a bash script?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the form `${VAR/subs}` where `VAR` contains the bigger string and
`subs` is the substring your are trying to find:

```
my_string=abc
substring=ab
if [ "${my_string/"$substring"}" = "$my_string" ] ; then
  echo "${substring} is not in ${my_string}"
else
  echo "${substring} was found in ${my_string}"
fi
```

This works because `${VAR/subs}` is equal to `$VAR` but with the first occurrence of the string `subs` removed, in particular if `$VAR` does not contains the word `subs` it won't be modified.

---

**Note:** As [jaimet](https://askubuntu.com/users/637246/jaimet) has commented, the `$substring` parameter in the `if` statement needs to be extra double-quoted, even though the `${..}` expression is already inside double quotes, to avoid any metacharacters in the substring retaining their "metacharacterness", i.e. being bitten by [SC2295](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2295).

Proof: if the `substring=ab` line was changed to `substring=[abcdefg]` without the extra double quotes, the program would then print `[abcdefg] was found in abc`.

Comment: Warning: you have not double-quoted your `$substring` parameter in your `if` statement, hence any metacharacters in your substring will retain their "metacharacterness" i.e. you will be bitten by [SC2295](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2295) Proof: change the `substring=ab` line to `substring=[abcdefg]` - your program will then print `[abcdefg] was found in abc` HTH

Comment: @jaimet Excellent observation! I have incorporated your comment into the answer!

Answer (score 50):

`[[ "bcd" =~ "ab" ]]`
`[[ "abc" =~ "ab" ]]`

The brackets are for the test, and as it is double brackets, it can do some extra tests like `=~`.

So you could use something like this form:

```
var1="ab"
var2="bcd"
if [[ "$var2" =~ "$var1" ]]; then
    echo "pass"
else
    echo "fail"
fi
```

Answer (score 13):

Using bash [filename patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) (aka "glob" patterns)

```
substr=ab
[[ abc == *"$substr"* ]] && echo yes || echo no    # yes
[[ bcd == *"$substr"* ]] && echo yes || echo no    # no
```

Comment: if [[ "$JAVA_OPTS" != *"-XX:+UseCompressedOops"* ]]; then export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseCompressedOops"; fi

Answer (score 10):

The following two approaches will work on any POSIX-compatible environment, not just in bash:

```sh
substr=ab
for s in abc bcd; do
    if case ${s} in *"${substr}"*) true;; *) false;; esac; then
        printf %s\\n "'${s}' contains '${substr}'"
    else
        printf %s\\n "'${s}' does not contain '${substr}'"
    fi
done
```

```sh
substr=ab
for s in abc bcd; do
    if printf %s\\n "${s}" | grep -qF "${substr}"; then
        printf %s\\n "'${s}' contains '${substr}'"
    else
        printf %s\\n "'${s}' does not contain '${substr}'"
    fi
done
```

Both of the above output:

```
'abc' contains 'ab'
'bcd' does not contain 'ab'
```

The former has the advantage of not spawning a separate `grep` process.

Note that I use `printf %s\\n "${foo}"` instead of `echo "${foo}"` because `echo` might mangle `${foo}` if it contains backslashes.

Comment: First version works perfectly for finding substring of monitor name in list of `xrandr` monitor names stored in variable. +1 and welcome to 1K rep club :)

Answer (score 6):

#### shell case statement

This is the most portable solution, will work even on old Bourne shells and Korn shell

```
#!/bin/bash
case "abcd" in
    *$1*) echo "It's a substring" ;;
    *) echo "Not a substring" ;;
esac
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./case_substr.sh "ab"                                                                                           
It's a substring
$ ./case_substr.sh "whatever"                                                                                     
Not a substring
```

Note that you don't have to specifically use `echo` you can use `exit 1` and `exit 0` to signify success or failure.

What we could do as well, is create a function (which can be used in large scripts if necessary) with specific return values ( 0 on match, 1 on no match):

```
$ ./substring_function.sh                                  
ab is substring

$ cat substring_function.sh                                
#!/bin/sh

is_substring(){
    case "$2" in
        *$1*) return 0;;
        *) return 1;;
    esac
}

main(){
   if is_substring "ab" "abcdefg"
   then
       echo "ab is substring"
   fi
}

main $@
```

#### grep

```
$ grep -q 'ab' <<< "abcd" && echo "it's a substring" || echo "not a substring"                                    
it's a substring
```

This particular approach is useful with if-else statements in `bash`. Also mostly portable

#### AWK

```
$ awk '$0~/ab/{print "it is a substring"}' <<< "abcd"                                                             
it is a substring
```

#### Python

```
$ python -c 'import sys;sys.stdout.write("it is a substring") if "ab" in sys.stdin.read() else exit(1)' <<< "abcd"
it is a substring
```

#### Ruby

```
$ ruby -e ' puts "is substring" if  ARGV[1].include? ARGV[0]'  "ab" "abcdef"                                             
is substring
```

Comment: +1 for going above and beyond everyone else. I noticed here and on other stack exchange sites no answer returns the substring's offset within the string. Which is tonight's mission :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Going to do that in bash ?

Comment: Yes and No. I'm doing a Frankenstein project where python get's all the gmail.com messages metadata and bash parses it and presents a GUI list with drill down. I found the answer though here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031764/position-of-a-string-within-a-string-using-linux-shell-script

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  OK. Sounds interesting.  I'd personally prefer to parse everything in Python. It has far more capabilities for text processing than bash alone.

Comment: I know your preferences for about two years and I respect them. But I'm just learning Python and getting yad to work within it seems cumbersome to me. Not to mention all the array processing which I'm already comfortable with in bash. But at least I wrote my first python script to suck everything out of google's gmail.com into Linux flat file right? :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yeah, that's true.  Speaking of  yad and zenity, feel free to look through some of my code on GitHub, I've used  in a lot of the programs a function to call zenity commands (or any other for that matter), which basically lists of strings.   But yes, good start on Python coding

Answer (score 5):

Mind the `[[` and `"`:

```
[[ $a == z* ]]   # True if $a starts with an "z" (pattern matching).
[[ $a == "z*" ]] # True if $a is equal to z* (literal matching).

[ $a == z* ]     # File globbing and word splitting take place.
[ "$a" == "z*" ] # True if $a is equal to z* (literal matching).
```

So as @glenn_jackman said, but mind that if you wrap the whole second term in double quotes, it will switch the test to *literal* matching.

Source: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Answer (score 5):

Similar to edwin's answer, but with improved portability for posix & ksh, and a touch less noisy than Richard's:

```
substring=ab

string=abc
if [ "$string" != "${string%"$substring"*}" ]; then
    echo "$substring IS in $string"
else
    echo "$substring is NOT in $string"
fi

string=bcd
if [ "$string" != "${string%"$substring"*}" ]; then
    echo "$string contains $substring"
else
    echo "$string does NOT contain $substring"
fi
```

Output:

```
abc contains ab
bcd does NOT contain ab
```

Comment: Warning: you have not quoted your `$substring` parameters in your `if` statements hence any metacharacters in your substrings will retain their "metacharacterness" i.e. you will be bitten by [SC2295](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2295) Proof: change your first line to `substring="[A ridiculously long substring]"` and your program's output becomes: `[A ridiculously long substring] IS in abc`
`bcd contains [A ridiculously long substring]`. HTH.

Comment: Much obliged, @jaimet . Fixed.